# try to curl to apple

Tags: php, curl

i used this code to curl with apple login

```
 <?php
$url = "https://appleid.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MyAppleId.woa/wa/directToSignIn?localang=en_US";
$post_data['theAccountName'] = "Email@email.com";
$post_data['theAccountPW'] = "mypassword";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
?>
```

but it didn't work for me any suggestion

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? Are there any error messages or unexpected results?

Comment: Also most probably this is violation of ToS, so Apple will not appreciate if finds out.

Comment: i see this 

An unknown error has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the ToS as pointed out by @Andrey.

But perhaps you have to set the HTTP method to POST?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: tried ths it didn't work is there any way to see hidden fileds

Comment: Try `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` after your `curl_exec($ch);` call to see if anything stands out.  Update your questions with this info dump.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php